# Compiling across different directories with GNU make

Tags: c, unit-testing, makefile, gnu-make

I have a project structure like such:

```
mcts/
    src/
        node_queue.c
        node_queue.h
    tests/
        munit.c    # testing frame work
        munit.h
        list_test.c # includes node_queue.h and munit.h
        Makefile    # Makefile in question
```

So my objective here is to compile the test mcts/test/list_test.c .  I have read a couple different strategies to doing this. After reading a bit I adapted some things I took from Makefiles into this:

```
CC= gcc
SOURCE= $(wildcard ../src/*.c ./*.c)
OBJECTS= $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCE))
INCLUDE= -I. -I../src/
CFLAGS= -std=c11 -g $(INCLUDE) -Werror -Wall

list_test: list_test.o munit.o ../src/node_queue.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ list_test.o munit.o    ../src/node_queue.o

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Which is the closest I've gotten in about 2 hours to working, when calling `make` in `mcts/tests` I receive the error:

```
list_test.o: In function `construct_test':
/home/----/mcts/tests/list_test.c:9: undefined reference to `construct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:8: list_test] Error 1
```

Where construct is defined in `mcts/src/node_queue.h`.
Shouldn't `$(INCLUDE)` ensure that the header is being included? 
And how can I get this to function?

Much thanks!

Comment: First, you don't need the `.c.o` rule - Make has that built in.

Comment: Second, it's probably preferable to use `VPATH` to specify the directories you want Make to search for objects, rather than baking paths into your dependencies and commands. I.e. you would say `list_test: list_test.o munit.o node_queue.o` and then the rule would run the command with arguments `-o $@ $^` to tell it to just reference all of the dependencies, wherever it found them.

Comment: @Novelocrat I was looking into `VPATH` but was reading [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/)  which made it seem like it was better to try other methods.

Comment: That article is addressing a particular kind of mis-use of VPATH. You would be using it as intended, I think

Answer (score 1):

For your actual error, you're reporting a linking error to an undefined symbol. If the object or function of that name were defined in `node_queue.h`, you would instead get a *multiple definition* error for `construct`.

What you probably are missing is that you have a declaration in that header, but no definition in `node_queue.c`.

Comment: Yeah I just lost 5 hours to spelling construct as contsruct... but I do have my Makefile in order now
[gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Beaudidly/b374790854a91f2e3f3f1c077381c571/raw/2c1488010ebc7d3c11b26bf34add51c63e04da25/Makefile)

Comment: It happens to all of us.